# Calling textvariable from function within a class Python 3 tkinter

Tags: python, class, tkinter, definition

Thankful for any assistance in my question.

I am using Python 3 with tkinter where I have setup multiple pages, however I am trying to call a specific textvariable which is in a class, within a definition and wondering if it's possible to do with the way I built my script.

It's quite a big script so I don't want to paste all the code here, I hope this will be enough.

Basically the class is called POIIN(tk.frame) and I am trying to call

```
class POPage(tk.Frame):
def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

    self.entryboxes()

def entryboxes(self):
    # Entry boxes + variables
    global voucher
    voucher = IntVar()
    entry_box3 = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=voucher, width=32, bg="lightgreen")
    entry_box3.place(x=435, y=151)
```

I am trying to call the textvariable by doing the following outside of the class:

```
def do_mssql():
try:
    if int(POPage.entryboxes(voucher).get()) > int(maxN):
        voucherchktext()
    elif int(voucher.get()) < int(minN):
        voucherchktext()

    else:
        sql()
except:
    vouchermissing()
```

However it seems to be calling the IntVar() and I don't get any error message, (quite new with Python)
Basically I can pull the voucher from another class (page) with just doing the int(voucher.get()).
I could of course rename the textvariable and call it that way (which I don't mind), but it would be great if there is any way around this.

Greatful for any help!

BR,

Comment: What exactly do you expect `POPage.entryboxes(voucher).get()` to do?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, but I would like it to fetch the textvariable value

Comment: How is that different from `voucher.get()`? It seems like you are sharing this global `voucher` object between several pages - and therefore also between several `tk.Entry` objects. Why does it need to be global in the first place?

Comment: It's needed since I will have an output in another function which is not within the class.
I think it's lack of my knowledge that restricts me here, I could probably rewrite it in a better way.
Maybe I can upload the whole code somewhere for you to have a look at?

Comment: If you like, you can post the entire code on pastebin and then post the link to it here. I can't guarantee that I'll be able to have a look at it until tomorrow, though.

Comment: Hey,

Please have a look: https://pastebin.com/kJHYM1iJ , basically the background is that I created an application for one window in the beginning where I didn't have different frames, but now (most likely because of the global and my lack of knowledge of python I am struggling. My goal is to print voucher, wfgroup, client and user from IINPage if this frame is active and print POPage values when that frame is active.

Comment: Take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for posting your entire code on pastebin. By looking at your code I can see that none of your classes actually take ownership of the `tkinter` widgets they create. In otherwords, they don't have any instance variables. I would suggest a radical redesign and getting rid of all `global` variables and objects - in this case it's a major code smell and suggests that there is a flaw in your design - and that's fine, you did say you were a beginner after all. I see a lot of good things in your code, too! Not to be one-sided...

Basically, the change I'm recommending is this: Each frame class should take ownership of the widgets they create. That includes things like `tk.Label`s, `tk.Button`s, `tk.Entry`s and `tk.IntVar`s among others.

The major benefit this provides, is that any instance of your frame class will have its own `tk.IntVar` (or whatever entry widget variable, like `tk.StringVar`) which it does not need to share with any of the other classes (you called it a `textvariable`). This makes sense if you think about it: Every `tk.Entry` widget is coupled with one variable object that keeps track of the user's entered data for that entry widget - if you create just one global entry variable and share it with all entry widgets in all frames, you could easily lose a user's entered data - there's really no reason to do that.

Try running/playing around with the following code snippet:

```
import tkinter as tk


class MyFrame(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="Some Text")
        self.label.pack()

        self.entry_var = tk.IntVar()
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.entry_var, width=32)
        self.entry.pack()

        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="Print this frame's 'entry_var'", command=lambda: print(self.entry_var.get()))
        self.button.pack()


class Application(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.title("Title")
        self.geometry("256x256")
        self.resizable(width=False, height=False)

        self.frames = []

        for frame in MyFrame(), MyFrame():
            self.frames.append(frame)
            frame.pack()

def main():

    application = Application()
    application.mainloop()

    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

You have a main `Application` (you call it `Ghost` in your example), which has multiple frames (my example only has one frame class, but the `Application` has two instances of that frame class). Each frame instance has an entry widget and a unique, completely separate and distinct corresponding entry variable object. There is no reason for frames to share the same entry variable object. Making the widgets and entry variable objects instance variables of their classes should eliminate your use of `global` variables entirely.

In my example, if I needed to get access to the values in the entry widgets from outside the classes - like in the `main` function for example, you would say `application.frames[0].entry_var.get()` to get the value in the first frame's entry widget.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this out, learning by doing is the way to go. Appreciate your input!